# jQuery unreliable on mobile device

Tags: android, jquery, ios

I've looked through a few other questions to see if they answered my issue, but I haven't found any so I am posting this. I'm working on a responsive template for a site [link](http://responsive.dealerpro.net/?rsc=0)

On mobile devices, touches, taps, etc. are causing unexpected results. For example, the menu works, but some touches / taps / swipes cause it to disappear unexpectedly.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't mentioned jquery mobile... have you tried using [that instead](http://jquerymobile.com)?

Comment: Hi Adam, I'm not using jQuery Mobile on this particular project, no.